# WPF Toolkit DataGridColumnHeader does not maintain Style after data reload

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I am using Toolkit DataGrid. There is a custom header style when user sorts any column. But the data is refreshed after every few seconds and the new datatable is retrived from the server(I made the data in datatable sort based on the original sort).But because of this the header goes back to the default look.
I have tried explicitly assigning the sortDirection on the column like...

```
theGrid.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(i).SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
```

This doesn't solve the issue either.

Anybody knows any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the SortDirection property on the DataGridColumn **after** updating the DataGrid itemssource so it can get the style.